# CRS problem: not recognizing the CRS of shapefiles to be the same for all

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, spatial-join

I'm attempting to aggregate (average) the attributes a point layer to polygon attributes (i.e. block groups and counties) via a spatial join. Both the points and polygons are in the same projection - I've tried both NAD 83 and WGS84. After filling out the "join attributes by location" pop up, I get one saying:

> CRS Warning! Warning: Input layers have non-matching CRS. This may cause unexpected results.

But they DON'T have non-matching CRS'. It gets to 15% processed, and every time I get a "Crash dumped: minidump written to C:..." etc.

My steps to remedy have included: rebooting my computer, resaving each shapefile with the correct CRS, and uninstalling then reinstalling QGIS. I can send screen shots/shapefiles/any more info.

Comment: Bad/invalid geometries in either point or polygon layer, or both?

Comment: Sharing the files via dropbox could help further.